# Query optimization (SQL Azure)

Tags: sql, optimization

I have a query with lots of subqueries. Execution time is about 8 seconds, which is very slow.
I used CSS SQL Azure Diagnostics to suggest some indexes, but it didnt help a lot
How can I optimize this query?

```
SELECT  'employee' as emplres_type, e.employee_id as emplres_id,
(isnull(e.name_last,'')+' '+e.name_first+' '+isnull(e.name_second,'')) as employee_title,
(SELECT SUM(ci.quantity) FROM items_employees ie LEFT JOIN check_items ci ON ci.item_id=ie.citem_id LEFT JOIN checks c ON ci.check_id=c.check_id WHERE ie.employee_id=e.employee_id AND ci.servprod_type='service' AND CAST(floor(CAST(c.payed as float)) as datetime)=:date) as services_n,
(SELECT SUM(ci.quantity) FROM items_employees ie LEFT JOIN check_items ci ON ci.item_id=ie.citem_id LEFT JOIN products p ON p.product_id=ci.servprod_id LEFT JOIN checks c ON ci.check_id=c.check_id WHERE ie.employee_id=e.employee_id AND ci.servprod_type='product' AND CAST(floor(CAST(c.payed as float)) as datetime)=:date AND consumable=0) as products_n,
(SELECT SUM(ci.quantity) FROM items_employees ie LEFT JOIN check_items ci ON ci.item_id=ie.citem_id LEFT JOIN products p ON p.product_id=ci.servprod_id LEFT JOIN checks c ON ci.check_id=c.check_id WHERE ie.employee_id=e.employee_id AND ci.servprod_type='product' AND CAST(floor(CAST(c.payed as float)) as datetime)=:date AND consumable=1) as consumables_n,
(SELECT SUM(isnull(ci.total,0)) FROM items_employees ie LEFT JOIN check_items ci ON ci.item_id=ie.citem_id LEFT JOIN checks c ON ci.check_id=c.check_id WHERE ie.employee_id=e.employee_id AND ci.servprod_type='service' AND CAST(floor(CAST(c.payed as float)) as datetime)=:date) as services,
(SELECT SUM(isnull(ci.total,0)) FROM items_employees ie LEFT JOIN check_items ci ON ci.item_id=ie.citem_id LEFT JOIN products p ON p.product_id=ci.servprod_id LEFT JOIN checks c ON ci.check_id=c.check_id WHERE ie.employee_id=e.employee_id AND ci.servprod_type='product' AND CAST(floor(CAST(c.payed as float)) as datetime)=:date AND consumable=0) as products,
(SELECT SUM(isnull(ci.total,0)) FROM items_employees ie LEFT JOIN check_items ci ON ci.item_id=ie.citem_id LEFT JOIN products p ON p.product_id=ci.servprod_id LEFT JOIN checks c ON ci.check_id=c.check_id WHERE ie.employee_id=e.employee_id AND ci.servprod_type='product' AND CAST(floor(CAST(c.payed as float)) as datetime)=:date AND consumable=1) as consumables,
(SELECT SUM(isnull(comm_spec_payed*percentage/100,0)) FROM items_employees ie LEFT JOIN check_items ci ON ci.item_id=ie.citem_id LEFT JOIN checks c ON ci.check_id=c.check_id WHERE ie.employee_id=e.employee_id AND ci.servprod_type='service' AND CAST(floor(CAST(c.payed as float)) as datetime)=:date) as comm_services,
(SELECT SUM(isnull(comm_spec_payed*percentage/100,0)) FROM items_employees ie LEFT JOIN check_items ci ON ci.item_id=ie.citem_id LEFT JOIN checks c ON ci.check_id=c.check_id WHERE ie.employee_id=e.employee_id AND ci.servprod_type='product' AND CAST(floor(CAST(c.payed as float)) as datetime)=:date) as comm_products,
(SELECT SUM(isnull(ie.to_balance,0)) FROM items_employees ie LEFT JOIN check_items ci ON ci.item_id=ie.citem_id LEFT JOIN checks c ON ci.check_id=c.check_id WHERE ie.employee_id=e.employee_id AND CAST(floor(CAST(c.payed as float)) as datetime)=:date) as comm_to_balance,
(SELECT SUM(a.commission_payed) FROM check_admins a LEFT JOIN checks c ON a.check_id=c.check_id WHERE a.employee_id=e.employee_id AND CAST(floor(CAST(c.payed as float)) as datetime)=:date) as comm_admin
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT employee_id  FROM schedule
WHERE work_type='work' AND CAST(floor(CAST([from] as float)) as datetime)=:date AND salon_id=:salon_id ) s
LEFT JOIN employees e ON s.employee_id=e.employee_id
```

Comment: Thats looks like a lot of correlated scalar subqueries.

Comment: You clearly have some understanding of JOINs so my first step would be to seperate each SELECT statement out into individual statements and then start integrating them as much as possible into one flat statement of the type `SELECT... FROM A LEFT JOIN B ... LEFT JOIN F`. All these nested subqueries will kill performance, trying to do as much as possible in one or two steps will get you much better performing SQL.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.